# Function to search for first occurrence of multiple strings or characters in a string

Tags: d

Is there anything built in to stdlib for multiple string search. I don't want to reinvent the wheel. std.string.indexOf handles single string and character searches but that's all i saw.

Comment: To clarify, you want to find the index of any of an array of strings within a single string e.g., find the first of ["ab", "cd", "ef"] within the string "sick abs, bro"?

Comment: yes. I think there's several algorithms for it but not sure what they're called

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> You could probably cheat and just use .ptr on the haystack and find
>   result slice with pointer arithmetic to get the index quickly but
>   that's only for supercool badasses

The real question is: Do you want an *index* or a *count*? Since we are talking about (unicode) strings, there is a fundamental difference.

`countUntil`, contrary to `indexOf`, returns an "ammount of popFronts", and not an array index. If your string contains unicode characters (which you should always assume), then it will blow in your face:

From http://dlang.org/phobos/std_algorithm.html#countUntil

```
assert(std.algorithm.countUntil("日本語", "本語") == 1);
assert(std.string.indexOf("日本語", "本語") == 3);
```

That said, this should be a more efficient. It does a single search:

```
void main()
{
    auto needles = [ "abc", "def", "ghi", "jkl" ];
    auto haystack = "日本語abcakllgfjekwralv";

    auto intermediary1 = find(haystack, "abc", "def", "ghi", "jkl")[0]; //"abcakllgfjekwralv""
    auto intermediary2 = haystack[0 .. haystack.length - intermediary1.length]; //"日本語"
    auto index = intermediary2.length;     // "日本語".length => 9
    auto count = intermediary2.walkLength; // "日本語" => 3
    assert(index == 9);
    assert(count == 3);
}
```

Comment: I'm glad you pointed that out.  English speakers like myself often forget code unit != code point.

Answer (score 3):

`std.algorithm.countUntil` is the usual way to find an index but it inexplicably doesn't accept multiple needles.  Several other std.algorithm functions do though.  This should work:

import std.algorithm, std.stdio;

```
void main()
{
    auto needles = [ "abc", "def", "ghi", "jkl" ];
    auto haystack = "fdjwabcakllgfjekwralv";

    auto pos = haystack.countUntil(find(haystack, "abc", "def", "ghi", "jkl")[0]);
    writeln(pos); // outputs: 4
}
```

find will find a matching needle and return a tuple with a slice of the position found to the end of the string and the index of the needle that matched.  Once you have the slice you can use countUntil to find its index.

It does require two searches unfortunately.  You could probably cheat and just use .ptr on the haystack and find result slice with pointer arithmetic to get the index quickly but that's only for supercool badasses.

Comment: Found the bug for countUntil not accepting multiple needles if you are curious: http://d.puremagic.com/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=5507

Answer (score 1):

Since you did not give an example of what you exactly need (with an example of an input, and an example of your expected output), I will just point out that you may want to learn more about the [std.algorithm](http://dlang.org/phobos/std_algorithm.html#find) module. You can perform all kinds of searches with it, not just with strings...